Link error using cmake, pico SDK and arm-none-eabi. Multiple definitions of main
Disclaimer: I'm fairly new to cmake and pico SDK and also to this forum so bear with me
Problem: In my c project I have a simple main function (just returning 0) and when I link I get "multiple definition of `main'" error.
If I omit my main function I get
"undefined reference to `main'" error.
UPDATE
If I move the file appl.c holding the main function to root directory
"/projects/software/pico/projects/projects/scrap" and add appl.c to list of executables in root CMakeLists.txt the project builds and links just fine. Added the output below.
Still interested in understanding the problem though!!
commands to build:

jss@Lubuntu:~/projects/software/pico/projects/projects/scrap$ cd build
jss@Lubuntu:~/projects/software/pico/projects/projects/scrap/build$ cmake ..
jss@Lubuntu:~/projects/software/pico/projects/projects/scrap/build$ make

output (only tail) with file appl.c in root
[  1%] Built target cyw43_driver_picow_cyw43_bus_pio_spi_pio_h
[  3%] Built target bs2_default
[  6%] Built target bs2_default_padded_checksummed_asm
[  7%] Building C object CMakeFiles/scrap.dir/appl.c.obj
[  8%] Linking CXX executable scrap.elf
[100%] Built target scrap

output (only tail) w main in appl.c

[  1%] Built target cyw43_driver_picow_cyw43_bus_pio_spi_pio_h
[  3%] Built target bs2_default
[  6%] Built target bs2_default_padded_checksummed_asm
[  7%] Linking CXX executable scrap.elf
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: /tmp/ccjyseXf.o: in function `main':
/home/jss/projects/software/pico/projects/projects/scrap/src/appl.c:11: multiple definition of `main'; CMakeFiles/scrap.dir/src/appl.c.obj:/home/jss/projects/software/pico/projects/projects/scrap/src/appl.c:11: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/scrap.dir/build.make:1307: scrap.elf] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1796: CMakeFiles/scrap.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2

==============================================================================================

without main

[  1%] Built target cyw43_driver_picow_cyw43_bus_pio_spi_pio_h
[  3%] Built target bs2_default
[  6%] Built target bs2_default_padded_checksummed_asm
[  7%] Linking CXX executable scrap.elf
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/13.2.1/../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/scrap.dir/home/jss/projects/software/pico/projects/projects/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_crt0/crt0.S.obj: in function `runtime_init':
/home/jss/projects/software/pico/projects/projects/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_crt0/crt0.S:291:(.reset+0x94): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/scrap.dir/build.make:1290: scrap.elf] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1796: CMakeFiles/scrap.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2


project structure:
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── log.txt
├── build
|    ....
└── src
    ├── appl.c
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── io
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   └── io.c
    └── parser
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        └── parser.c


#CMakeLists.txt top level
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)

# initialize the SDK based on PICO_SDK_PATH
set(PICO_SDK_PATH "/home/jss/projects/software/pico/projects/projects/pico-sdk")
set(PICO_BOARD pico_w)


# initialize the SDK based on PICO_SDK_PATH
# note: this must happen before project()
include(${PICO_SDK_PATH}/external/pico_sdk_import.cmake)

set(this scrap)
variable_watch(this)
variable_watch(src)

project(${this} C CXX ASM)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
#set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)

#set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

message("Building project ${PROJECT_NAME}")

# initialize the Raspberry Pi Pico SDK
pico_sdk_init()


set(src)
add_subdirectory("src")

# Create target
add_executable(
  ${this}
  "${src}"
)

# Add pico_stdlib library which aggregates commonly used features
# Add pico_w arch
if (PICO_CYW43_SUPPORTED)
    target_link_libraries(${this} ${src} pico_stdlib pico_cyw43_arch_none)
else()
    target_link_libraries(${this} pico_stdlib)
endif()

# create map/bin/hex/uf2 file in addition to ELF.
pico_add_extra_outputs(${this})


#CMakeLists.txt in src

#set(module main PRIVATE)
set(dir "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")

#list(
#  APPEND src
#  "${dir}/appl.c"
#)

add_subdirectory("io")
add_subdirectory("parser")

#target_include_directories(module
#  PUBLIC
#    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}
#  )

set(src "${src}" PARENT_SCOPE)



#CMakeLists.txt in src/io
#set(module io PRIVATE)
set(dir "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")

list(
  APPEND src
  "${dir}/io.c"
)

set(src "${src}" PARENT_SCOPE)

Trying to link source files w pico_stdlib pico_cyw43_arch_none using cmake, pico SDK and pico tool chain
